# How to simplify statement with the sprintf?

Tags: c, pic, mplab

Is there possible to simplify this statement with the sprintf?

```
 unsigned char text[50];
 void decode (unsigned char* msg)
 {
     // ON LED
     if (strstr (msg, "DO1=1") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG1 =1 ; //led1 on
         sprintf(text,"OK"); // Send the result in HyperTerminal
         sendString(text) ;
     }
     else if (strstr (msg, "DO2=1") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG0 = 0 ; //LED 2 on
         sprintf(text,"OK"); // Send the result in HyperTerminal
         sendString(text) ;
     }
     else if (strstr (msg, "DO3=1") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //LED 3 on
         sprintf(text,"OK"); // Send the result in HyperTerminal
         sendString(text) ;
     }
     else if (strstr (msg, "DO4=1") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //LED 4 on
         sprintf(text,"OK"); // Send the result in HyperTerminal
         sendString(text) ;
     }
     else if (strstr (msg, "DO5=1") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //LED 5 on
         sprintf(text,"OK"); // Send the result in HyperTerminal
         sendString(text) ;
     }

     // OFF LED
     else if (strstr (msg, "DO1=0") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG1 =0 ; //LED 1 off
     }
          else if (strstr (msg, "DO2=0") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //LED 2 off
     }
          else if (strstr (msg, "DO3=0") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //LED 3 off
     }
          else if (strstr (msg, "DO4=0") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //LED 4 off
     }
          else if (strstr (msg, "DO5=0") == msg)
     {
         LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //LED 5 off
     }

 }
```

From the code above shows, for example, when the word `"DO1=1"` is type in HyperTerminal, the LED1 will turn ON and `"DO1=0"` will turn OFF the LED. Same with DO1 until DO5. Answers depend on definition of the type of `LATGbits`.

Comment: Note that these checks will give false positives for something like `"DO5=01"` - was that intended?

Comment: @MattMcNabb , yup these checks will give false positives. There are nothing happened when `DO5=01`. But it seems OK to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it consists entirely of mutually exclusive options, you can get rid of all the `else if` bits with a bit of judicious refactoring.

In addition, the way you're comparing the strings means they have to be at the start, so you can get away with `strncmp`.

And, there's no need to copy a string literal to a buffer then send the buffer, when you can just send the string literal.

Making those change would result in code like:

```
#define okayReturn { sendString("OK"); return; }
void decode (unsigned char* msg) {
    if (strncmp (msg, "DO1=1", 5) == 0) {
        LATGbits.LATG1 = 1;
        okayReturn;
    }

    if (strncmp (msg, "DO2=1", 5) == 0) {
        LATGbits.LATG0 = 0;
        okayReturn;
    }

    :

    if (strncmp (msg, "DO5=0", 5) == 0) {
        LATGbits.LATG12 = 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

---

Another alternative is to split the string into three sections (`DO`, `n` and `=v` where `n` is one of the digits `1..5` and `v` is either `0` or `1`).

Then you can put together a data driven approach using variable pointers, such as with:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void decode (unsigned char* msg) {
    // Variables to change for each n in DOn=v

    static int *vars[] = { &LATGbits.LATG1, &LATGbits.LATG0,
        &LATGbits.LATG13, &LATGbits.LATG14, &LATGbits.LATG12 };

    // Check content, allowing for upper/lower case.

    msg[0] = toupper (msg[0]);
    msg[1] = toupper (msg[1]);

    if ((msg[0] != 'D') && (msg[1] != 'O')) return;
    if ((msg[2] < '1') || (msg[2] > '5')) return;
    if (msg[3] != '=') return;
    if ((msg[4] != '0') && (msg[4] != '1')) return;

    // Special case for LED 1 vs 2-5.

    int on = (msg[2] == '1') ? 1 : 0;

    // All content validated, make change, first turning on.

    if (msg[4] == '1') {
        *(vars[msg[2] - '1']) = on;
        sendString("OK");
        return;
    }

    // Or turning off.

    *(vars[msg[2] - '1']) = 1 - on;
}
```

Note the use of `toupper()` to force the first two character to uppercase. This allows you to enter either case and it will be treated the same. If you *need* case sensitivity, simply remove those two lines.

Although this is a little more complex, it's much shorter, *especially* if you decide to add more LEDs later on.

---

Keep in mind that this will work only if the variables in `vars` are actually addressable. That *won't* be the case if they're bit fields but, even then, you can use some of the shortening methods above to minimise the code length and thereby make it more maintainable:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void decode (unsigned char* msg) {
    // Check content, allowing for upper/lower case.

    msg[0] = toupper (msg[0]);
    msg[1] = toupper (msg[1]);

    if ((msg[0] != 'D') && (msg[1] != 'O')) return;
    if ((msg[2] < '1') || (msg[2] > '5')) return;
    if (msg[3] != '=') return;
    if ((msg[4] != '0') && (msg[4] != '1')) return;

    // All content validated, make change, either turning off.

    if (msg[4] == '0') {
        switch (msg[2]) {
            case '1': LATGbits.LATG1 = 0; break;
            case '2': LATGbits.LATG0 = 1; break;
            case '3': LATGbits.LATG13 = 1; break;
            case '4': LATGbits.LATG14 = 1; break;
            case '5': LATGbits.LATG12 = 1; break;
        }
        return;
    }

    // Or turning on.

    switch (msg[2]) {
        case '1': LATGbits.LATG1 = 1; break;
        case '2': LATGbits.LATG0 = 0; break;
        case '3': LATGbits.LATG13 = 0; break;
        case '4': LATGbits.LATG14 = 0; break;
        case '5': LATGbits.LATG12 = 0; break;
        default:  return;
    }
    sendString("OK");
}
```

That's still short and only a *little* less easy to expand on should you wish to add LEDs. However, if you have to update bit fields, it's still well-structured and easy to understand.

Comment: when I tried to, I got an `error: cannot take address of bit-field 'LATG1' .. until LATG12` . that means `static int` is not suitable for `LATG` ?

Comment: @athirah, I didn't realise they were bitfiedls so, no, you can't take the address of them. However, you can still use the other methods to make your code both shorter and more maintainable, see the update.

Comment: i noticed something, when i press `enter` , to write new word, it return the word `OK` . that means  `sendString("OK");` is written outside bracket ?

Comment: @athirah: not entirely certain on your question in the comment but, for turning on in the final code block, it will write OK as long as the LED was 1..5. Otherwise the switch default case kicks in and it returns before writing.

Comment: paxdiablo: thanks for good example and explanation :) .
but from your code, when `d01=1` it will turn off and  `d01=0`it will turn on ;)

Comment: @athirah, yes, that LED2-5 behaviour confused me to the point where I didn't know *what* was on and off :-) Have fixed now (at least I *think* I have) in both data-driven and final code block. Just to confirm, LED1 on is 1, LED2-5 on is 0 (and opposite for off of course).

Comment: paxdiablo: yes, now the result is OK. LED1 on is 1, LED2-5 on is 0 ;-)

Comment: paxdiablo: is there possible to ignore, the UPPER CASE or lower case,
`if ((msg[0] != 'D','d') && (msg[1] != 'O','o')) return;` or using library ?

Comment: @athirah, yes, `#include <ctype.h>` and then insert `msg[0] = toupper(msg[0]); msg[1] = toupper(msg[1]);` before the checks that are currently there. Made the changes to the code to allow this.

Answer (score 1):

You could change to this:

```
unsigned char text[50];
void decode (unsigned char* msg)
{
    int on = 0;
    // ON LED
    if (strstr (msg, "DO1=1") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG1 =1 ; //led1 on
        on = 1;
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO2=1") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG0 = 0 ; //LED 2 on
        on = 1;
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO3=1") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //LED 3 on
        on = 1;
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO4=1") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //LED 4 on
        on = 1;
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO5=1") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //LED 5 on
        on = 1;
    }

    // OFF LED
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO1=0") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG1 =0 ; //LED 1 off
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO2=0") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //LED 2 off
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO3=0") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //LED 3 off
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO4=0") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //LED 4 off
    }
    else if (strstr (msg, "DO5=0") == msg)
    {
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //LED 5 off
    }

    if (on)
    {
        sprintf(text,"OK"); // Send the result in HyperTerminal
        sendString(text) ;
    }
}
```